# ActionBarSherlock Omnibus v3.8

Tags: android, commonsware

I tried to import ActionBarSherlock in sub folder external of omnibus v3.8 but I got so many errors (more than 150). Most of them are about override a super class method.

If I remove @Override annotation at the error line, the error is gone. Should I remove it one by one (more than 150 error) ? Is there any shortcut way to remove all errors?

The release of ADT plugin : 18.0.0
JDK : 1.7
Build target : 15

Thanks

Comment: How accept answer, click the Yes button in the "Was this post useful to you?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code that you imported is from http://github.com/commonsware/cw-omnibus. If you read that Web page, you will find instructions for use of that code. If you read those instructions, you will find that:

- You need to have your Java compliance level set to 1.6 and
- You may need to adjust the ActionBarSherlock project to build with a build target that you have installed, or to install API Level 14 (which, IIRC, is what ActionBarSherlock wants)

Comment: @user1134475: "Does it mean I can't use Jdk 1.7" -- I have never tested on Java 7, as that's not officially supported yet by the Android toolchain. It also is irrelevant, as I am referring to your Java compliance level in Eclipse, not the version of the Java compiler that you are using. "nor use build target 15" -- a build target of 15 should be fine for ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: I see.. After changing the compliance level to 1.6, the errors become ...cannot be resolved a type. For instance : ActionBar cannot be resolved a type. I also get this error in abs__styles.xml : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment. It has been fixed. Thanks a lot